# Mixed calling conventions make compilation errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stdcall, cdecl

I have a library (C++) which has some API functions. One of them is declared as __cdecl, but gets a function poiner from __stdcall. Something like:

```
typedef  int (__stdcall *Func)(unsigned char* buffer);
//...
int ApiFunc(Func funcPtr); //This is __cdecl since it is an 'extern "C"' library and the calling convention is not specified
```

Then - I have a C++ executable project which uses this library, but doesn't call the above API or uses the `Func` type.

After changing the calling convention of `Func` to `__stdcall`, I get the following compilation error:

> error C2995:
>   'std::pointer_to_unary_function<_Arg,_Result,_Result(__cdecl *)(_Arg)> std::ptr_fun(_Result (__cdecl *)(_Arg))' : function
>   template has already been
>   defined   c:\program files\microsoft
>   visual studio 8\vc\include\functional

Any idea what could it be?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Err.. they're incompatible. You have to specify the same calling convention on both sides of the call. Otherwise attempting to call will blow up the machine stack.

Comment: Could we mix calling conventions though across a project? Say on MSVS/windows where all functions are __stdcall/WINAPI by default, could we make some function follow a different calling convention, say __fastcall (perhaps to improve performance) and some others __thicall. So in general can we mix calling conventions?

Comment: As long as the calling convention is present in the signature, sure. But that's not mixing calling convention -- callee and caller would agree.

Comment: @BillyNNeal Yeah, I only meant having different calling conventions for different functions across a program. So that's possible. Ok, cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They ARE compatible, in Windows at least (and in Linux there isn't __stdcall at all...)
The problem was that by mistake, the library re-defined __stdcall for compatibility with Linux, as:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_WIN32
//Just an empty define for Linux compilation
#define __stdcall
#endif
```

The exe project includes this definition, and __MYLIB_WIN32 was not defined in it, but in the library only.
Changing the above definition to:

```
#ifndef WIN32
//Just an empty define for Linux compilation
#define __stdcall
#endif
```

and everything works fine.

Thank you all.